# What's the difference between these two pieces of code?

Tags: java, android

These are two intents which start another activity named StartActivity.
They both run in different contexts but are not replaceable.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, StartActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: if directly (ie. not in an anonymous inner) in `MainActivity`, none.

Comment: Okay. So if I have to go to some other part of the same activity I use this, else I use the name of activity to go to, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would see the first syntax when this code appears in an inner class of `MainActivity`, such as the anonymous inner class implementation of `View.OnClickListener` that you create for a `setOnClickListener()` call. It says "the `this` we want is the instance of `MainActivity`, not the instance of the `View.OnClickListener` implementation".

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use MainActivity.this when there are multiple wrapping classes.

E.g.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      // this refers to the Runnable
      // MainActivity.this refers to the activity
    }
  };

}
```